# Blurr edge of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, blur

Is there any way to blur only the edge of a bitmap not complete bitmap. I have gone through Guasian blur and more but those blur the bitmap complttely. I want to blur right edge of bit map so that there will be no right edge on the bitmap?

Comment: check out [this link](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-blur-edge-on-bitmap-using.html)

Comment: I have already used that, but it blurs all four edges of the bitmap with the given radius. But i need to blur single edge(Right edge) of bitmap.